# Laravel Heroku Application error

Tags: php, heroku, laravel-5.4

I am developing a Laravel 5.4 app.I have deployed it to Heroku ,`running on free dyno` and everything was working fine.I am using google drive as my cloud storage.After uploading a file,size of 200 mb ,I am getting this error:

```
                          Application error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.
 If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I have saved a .user.ini in my project root,which I have edited like this:

```
post_max_size = 450M

upload_max_filesize = 400M

memory_limit =800M
```

I have tried to tail the log,but failed to point out the error.

```
2017-09-08T14:11:11.641039+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.39.212 - - [08/Sep/2017:14:10:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; en-US; Redmi Note 3 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/11.4.2.995 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
2017-09-08T14:11:11.640651+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Sep 08 14:11:11.639951 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 199:tid 140229860124416] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.30.39.212:29863] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
2017-09-08T14:11:31.916721+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Sep 08 14:11:31.916070 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 119:tid 140229692311296] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.178.162.66:30441] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
2017-09-08T14:11:31.916923+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.178.162.66 - - [08/Sep/2017:14:10:31 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0.1; en-US; Redmi Note 3 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/11.4.2.995 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
2017-09-08T14:16:36.566647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=18348fb3-4aa1-44d1-84e0-9944c0e3ca90 fwd="119.30.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2017-09-08T14:17:06.636366+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.142.142.206 - - [08/Sep/2017:14:16:06 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-08T14:17:06.636209+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Sep 08 14:17:06.634709 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 199:tid 140229964785408] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.142.142.206:33015] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
2017-09-08T14:17:19.864896+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=588M(110.3%)
2017-09-08T14:17:19.864994+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2017-09-08T14:17:40.187463+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.226.198 - - [08/Sep/2017:14:06:26 +0000] "POST /google HTTP/1.1" 200 42 "http://namepedia.herokuapp.com/test" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-08T14:17:40.180242+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/google" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=b5602546-0837-487b-b024-ab8686063d12 fwd="182.48.66.118" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=673737ms status=200 bytes=989 protocol=http
```

[image: Memory Quota Exceeded]

File Upload Controller:

```
public function fileupolad(Request $request){

$files = $request->file('files');

if($request->hasFile('files')){


foreach ($files as $file) {

   $filedata=new NameFile;

  $subject = $request->input('subject');
  $type = $request->input('type');

  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

  $onlyname=basename($file->getClientOriginalName(), '.'.$file-
  >getClientOriginalExtension());

   $myfile=Storage::disk('google')->put($name,File::get($file));

   $listContents = Storage::disk('google')->listContents();

  $fileid = $this->getId($listContents, 'filename', $onlyname);

  $id = $fileid['path'];
  $filedata->file=$file->getClientOriginalName();;

   $filedata->subject_id=$subject;

   $filedata->fileid=$id;
   $filedata->type=$type;
   $filedata->extension=$extension;

   $filedata->save();

}

}

}
```

Update:

I have changed the Upload controller like this:

```
$myfile=Storage::disk('google')->put($name,fopen($file,'r+'));
```

While uploading file,If anyone tries to go into my site they are facing `Application Error`.

Now,I am getting this error log.
[image: Another Error Log]

```
2017-09-08T16:38:04.910262+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.229.116.254 - - [08/Sep/2017:16:37:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-08T16:38:38.677784+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=2bb46915-8ad8-4de8-9208-c4eb7c9a92d6 fwd="119.30.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2017-09-08T16:38:40.006721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=6fead786-23fa-4f3c-b2b0-d459a0a48d84 fwd="119.30.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=1386 protocol=http
2017-09-08T16:38:40.004373+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.61.201.223 - - [08/Sep/2017:16:38:40 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "http://namepedia.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-08T16:39:08.741910+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.71.219.155 - - [08/Sep/2017:16:38:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-08T16:39:08.741755+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Sep 08 16:39:08.741069 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 115:tid 140448668550912] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.71.219.155:16019] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
2017-09-08T16:40:09.596516+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=d5c2b995-20d8-476c-8668-7810299c08c4 fwd="119.30.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2017-09-08T16:40:12.326462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=e8b549cb-4f2c-4e4e-b9e7-556e7929d653 fwd="119.30.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=1386 protocol=http
2017-09-08T16:40:12.325932+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.99.212.2 - - [08/Sep/2017:16:40:12 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "http://namepedia.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; en-us; Redmi Note 4 Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.146 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/9.0.3
2017-09-08T16:40:39.659167+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Sep 08 16:40:39.658830 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 113:tid 140448601425664] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.16.227.159:59248] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
2017-09-08T16:40:39.659415+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.16.227.159 - - [08/Sep/2017:16:39:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 7.0; en-us; Redmi Note 4 Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.146 Mobile Safari/537.36 XiaoMi/MiuiBrowser/9.0.3
2017-09-08T16:43:15.300665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=b92d0da8-7eb3-4a4c-99aa-1a62a0e5e5b0 fwd="119.30.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
2017-09-08T16:43:16.358949+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=namepedia.herokuapp.com request_id=f1b72007-6f8d-4b25-851e-3de9e093ff49 fwd="119.30.32.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=1386 protocol=http
2017-09-08T16:43:16.362201+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.45.224.229 - - [08/Sep/2017:16:43:16 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1150 "http://namepedia.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
2017-09-08T16:43:45.361523+00:00 app[web.1]: [Fri Sep 08 16:43:45.361082 2017] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 197:tid 140448567863040] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 10.146.95.78:54462] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
2017-09-08T16:43:45.361678+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.146.95.78 - - [08/Sep/2017:16:42:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me that you exceeded Heroku's memory limit, a quick glace at their page shows 512MB RAM, setting PHP's memory_limit higher than Heroku's available isn't going to do anything...

Comment: So,I have to buy memory. Shouldn't it solve my problem?

Comment: You need to look into streaming these files rather than reading their entire contents into memory.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're reading the file into memory before saving it into your storage disk. There's a much simpler method for doing this that uses streaming by default and gets around any memory issues. I've tested this successfully with a 1GB file upload on a free Heroku dyno and there are no memory or locking issues.

Note, this example uses S3, but if you're using the [Flysystem](https://flysystem.thephpleague.com/docs/) driver for Google it's the same basic concept. The key is that we're not creating a variable that reads in the full file, we're simply handing off the file from the Request directly to storage. By default, this gives us the `$path` back, so your extra call to `listContents()` can be avoided as well

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {

            $path = $request->file('file')->store('/', 's3');

            return $path;
        }

    }
```

The only other thing to make sure of is that your php.ini overrides (in `.user.ini`) match the maximum file sizes you wish to support.